# Configure the OOM to avoid having the system grind to a halt

Tags: memory, out-of-memory

I have an SSD and therefore no swap. However, when I open a lot of tabs in the browser, the system tends to grind to a halt. If I'm lucky, I can close one or two tabs before the system is completely unresponsive. Is it possible to use the OOM in this case to kill a few browser processes (chromium) to avoid the unresponsiveness? There is still a bit of memory available, but apparently there's still a resource conflict.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't directly answer your question about OOM but I've used this technique for a while now where you can enable the "Purge Memory" button within Chrome's Task Manager dialog.

#### Example

You'll need to modify how Chrome starts by adding this command line switch.

```
$ chrome --purge-memory-button
```

Once enabled when you summon the Task Manager dialog using the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, you'll see an extra button which you can tell Chrome to release RAM that is not critical to what contents currently being displayed within your tabs.

[image: ss of TM]

#### References

- [How to Purge Memory in Google Chrome](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7416/how-to-purge-memory-in-google-chrome/)
- [Monitor and Control Memory Usage in Google Chrome](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16102/monitor-and-control-memory-usage-in-google-chrome/)